# Encountering a derefrencing error

Tags: java

```
public class Temperaturevar {
    public int T1 = 0;
    public int T2;
    public int T3;
    public int T4;
    public int T5;
    public int T6;
    public int T7;
    public int T8;
    public int T9;
    public int T10;

    public Temperaturevar() {
    }

    public void TemperatureVar() {
        T1 = T1;
        T2 = T1 + 10;
        T3 = T2 + 10;
        T4 = T3 + 10;
        T5 = T4 + 10;
        T6 = T5 + 10;
        T7 = T6 + 10;
        T8 = T7 + 10;
        T9 = T8 + 10;
        T10 = T9 + 10;
        //increase Temperature value by 10
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return T1;
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("T1: " + T1.getValue());
        System.out.println("T2: " + T2.getValue());
        System.out.println("T3: " + T3.getValue());
        System.out.println("T4: " + T4.getValue());
        System.out.println("T5: " + T5.getValue());
        System.out.println("T6: " + T6.getValue());
        System.out.println("T7: " + T7.getValue());
        System.out.println("T8: " + T8.getValue());
        System.out.println("T9: " + T9.getValue());
        System.out.println("T10: " + T10.getValue());
    }
}
```

I am relatively new to Java programming and understand the basics but I keep encountering the `int cannot be derefrenced` error when I try to print out he values for `T1`-`T10`. I have also tried using the click method which succeeded but then I ran into the issue where I have to store the respective number to the variable so I can reference it for another class.

Comment: What do you expect `T1.getValue()` to return? Why?

Answer (score 1):

So, there are multiple issues with your code and I will try to get you in the right direction, but there may still be issues at that point.

The biggest issue is that integers are primitive types, so you cannot create a getValue() method and call that from the integer. An int will implicitly give you its value so you can just write 'T1' instead of 'T1.getValue()'.

For the record, the way that your getValue() function is currently written, it can only be called by a TemperatureVar object and it would only ever return the value of T1.

Also note that you are never initializing your variables. Your code starts in main() so the code in public void TemperatureVar() never gets run.

Finally, I would look up arrays and for loops. They will make this code a lot less tedious, for example, if you need to make 100 steps of variance.